# Calculate the Hamming Distance between the two same datasets

Tags: dataset, distance-functions, measurement-error

How to Calculate the Hamming Distance between two datasets of same points?Both the data sets look exactly the same.
http://postimg.org/image/u11qnsolh/

There are two datasets of same number of points.
total number of points -19

---

First data set has 3 clusters.
Cluster A has 4 points in it
Cluster B has 2 points in it
Cluster C has 4 points in it

Rest of the points are outside the cluster

---

Second data set has 3 clusters.
Cluster A has 8 points in it
Cluster B has 5 points in it
Cluster C has 6 points in it

Comment: For the [definition of Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) with which I am familiar (in coding theory), this question makes no sense at all.  Could please tell us what *your* definition is?